# "get" Image blocked by CORB

Tags: html, image, error-handling

I'm trying to get a gif (or image) from the site ibb.co (free image hoster) and diplay it with html. The image is public so I think the program can access it. But CORB error don't let me load the image.

Here is the line that doesn't work :

```
<img src="https://ibb.co/FBfYndh" >
```

The error is the following : "Response was blocked by CORB (Cross-Origin Read Blocking)"

HTML is not at fault, for sure. Maybe the gif is too big (1.40 Mb) or the html code can't access it, but I checked and it's a public image.
I don't want to create a proxy site (takes too much time and resources), and I don't truly think the issue lies here.

If ibb.co site is really at fault, is there any alternative for posting images online and access it with HTML ?

Comment: The resource at that URL is not an image, and it has no way of knowing it should be one, so it's going to be like embedding HTML into an `img` tag, it's not allowed. Just host it yourself instead of using these services to lighten your load "for free".

Comment: If you can grab the actual image URL, it works: https://jsfiddle.net/ayonjtxu/